# Unable to get WPF element's parent?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some XAML in my WPF app as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}">...
```

Inside `myconverter`'s, `Convert()` method, the code:

```
    private static readonly PropertyInfo InheritanceContextProp = typeof(DependencyObject).GetProperty("InheritanceContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //the following does not work (parent returns null)
        var gvc1 = (value as GridViewColumn);
        var parent = InheritanceContextProp.GetValue(gvc1, null) as DependencyObject;

        //the following works (parent is not null)
        var gv = new GridView();
        var gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
        gv.Columns.Add(gvc2);
        parent = InheritanceContextProp.GetValue(gvc2, null) as DependencyObject;

        return 0;
    }
```

I've tried using `LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent()` and `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` on `gvc1` and neither of those work either (return null or throw an exception).

Can anyone explain what is going on, and why the second example works?

Comment: Rather than sending the GVC into the binding, send in the GridView.  Give it an x:Name and use an ElementName binding--`{Binding ElementName=MyNamedGridView, Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}`

Comment: @Will Thanks (`FindAncestor` also works in this case). My question was more academic - I don't understand \*why\* I can't traverse `gvc1`

Comment: Probably because the GridViewColumn doesn't exist within the logical or visual trees.  I dunno.  You'd have to check the source code.  It's not surprising.  Just because it's an element in an xaml tree doesn't mean it's automatically part of the visual/logical trees.  xaml just defines an object graph.  Some of those objects are used by controls to construct the UI and aren't necessarily actually used within it. :/

Comment: I've just had a look at the hierarchy in WPF Inspector and visual tree is going something like `GridViewColumnHeader (gvc)` << `GridViewColumnRowPresenter` << `ScrollContentPresenter` << `Grid`. How can this object not have a parent?

Comment: Because... it doesn't have a parent?  Because magic?  Dunno.  I try not to question the magic, as when you do it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but I randomly came across it and I have a theory which explains things.

Think about how the XAML processor has to build the controls when parsing the XAML. Going down the file, it will create a `ListView`, create a `GridView`, and then set the `ListView.View` property to that new `GridView` object. Realize, it had to finish creating the `GridView` before it could assign that property.

Now it gets to the `<GridViewColumn ...` line. It has to finish creating that `GridViewColumn` before it can add it to the `GridView.Columns` property. In parsing the line (creating the `GridViewColumn`), it comes across `Width="{Binding ...` and has to evaluate the binding, which means it also has to evaluate the converter.

So the converter gets invoked as part of parsing/creating the `GridViewColumn`, *before* it's actually added to the `GridView`, which explains why it's "parentless".

This explains why your second block of code *does* work, even when the first doesn't. You wait until after `Columns.Add` to call `InheritanceContextProp.GetValue`.

You can further test this by adding the following code to your converter:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
{
    var gvc1 = (value as GridViewColumn);
    var parent = InheritanceContextProp.GetValue(gvc1, null) as DependencyObject;
}));
```

This runs the code *after* WPF finishes loading everything. If you set a breakpoint, you will see that `parent` does get set correctly, now that you've waited. Of course, this isn't helpful for actually getting the converter to work, but it does explain *why* it isn't working.